# How to include the trace information while using my own log function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I have a custom log function like this.

```js
const myLog = (...args) => {
  const [first, ...rest] = args;
  console.log('%c' + first, 'color:red;', ...rest);
};

function foo() {
  console.log('hello');
  myLog('hello');
}

foo();
```

Whenever I logout something using this function, the trace information always points to the log function itself, which is super inconvenient that I want to find out which line of code is logging the message.

Is it possible to make it like the native `console.log` function, that points to the location that `myLog` is called? (Instead of line 3, I want it to point to line 8)

[image: log]

[image: trace]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`console.trace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/trace) instead of log. This will have clickable links to the full stack trace.

```js
console.trace('%c' + first, 'color:red;', ...rest);
```

Screenshot from jsfiddle:

[image]

Comment: This works, but It makes the logs extremely long. Wish there's a cleaner solution.